# numpy arrays written from image by opencv can't go over 255

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

if I have

```
im = cv2.read("path")
im = im+300
```

the values in `im` will be the remainder of `(im + 300) % 255`

any idea why or how to stop this behavior?

Comment: The image must be 8-bit (uint8). So convert the image to float or 16-bit ints

Comment: Thanks! that worked

Answer (score 0):

When you read an image into an array, each pixel of the image will be represented by three unsigned 8-bit integers (This is the default, aka 24-bit depth). An unsigned 8-bit integer can hold values from 0-255, and as such will roll over if you go above it. So, for instance, 254 + 2 = 0. That's why your values are modulo 256.

This is desirable behavior unless you specifically want a higher bit-depth.